# Why the size of disk block should be power of 2?

Tags: operating-system, filesystems

Is it about the shift operator? If so, how these two things connect together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that makes everything faster. All the arithmetic operations like addition, multiplication would be just about left/right shifting or toggling bits.

Example: Let the frame size is S. To access an index j, of the ith frame, we need:

```
index = S*i + j
```

If S is 2p, S*i will be:  i left shifted by p. Which is much faster than multiplying two arbitrary numbers